# React input - no default value

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am so confused, I have no idea what is wrong. the default value does only **sometimes** show up, and sometimes when the default value shows up, if I press enter or click submit it results in being an empty string.

**My Desired Outcome is:** I want the input to show the default value, which is dueDateObject.dueDate. And then I want to be able to submit the input with the default value and have it being saved.

**Problem**::: Now when I save the default value, it sometimes saves it as an empty string.

Thanks in advance :)

```
state = {
    editDueDateText: ''
}
```

```
onChangeEditDueDate = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      editDueDateText: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

```
editDueDate = (e, keyName, dueDateObject) => {
    dueDateObject.showEditDate = false;
    this.props.editDueDate({ keyName, dueDateObject, editText: this.state.editDueDateText })
  }
```

```
 <input className="form-control"
              onKeyDown={(e) => this.editDueDatekeypress(e, keyName, dueDateObject)}
              onChange={this.onChangeEditDueDate}
              value={this.state.editDueDateText}
              defaultValue={dueDateObject.dueDate}
              type="text"
              placeholder="By 28th May, I will have" />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                type="button"
                onClick={(e) => this.editDueDate(e, keyName, dueDateObject)}>Submit</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired outcome.. you are passing an empty string as a value to input and you want it to not accept this?

Comment: My Desired Outcome is: I want the input to show the default value, which is dueDateObject.dueDate. And then I want to be able to submit the input with the default value and have it being saved. 
-----------------------------------
A problem is:   Now when I save the default value, it sometimes saves it as an empty string.

Comment: where does `dueDateObject` come from?

Comment: It's an object that I pass down from the code above, but the thing is that if I take away the code "value={this.state.editDueDateText}", then all works but the problem is that instead of saving my default value when I submit the input it is an empty string

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by:
Deleting this code snippet: value={this.state.editDueDateText} and adjusting with some conditional statements along the way in the function below.

```
editDueDate = (e, keyName, dueDateObject) => {
    dueDateObject.showEditDate = false;

    if (this.state.editDueDateText) {
      this.props.editDueDate({ keyName, dueDateObject, editText: this.state.editDueDateText })
      this.setState({
        editDueDateText: ''
      })
    } else {
      this.props.editDueDate({ keyName, dueDateObject, editText: dueDateObject.dueDate })
      this.setState({
      editDueDateText:''
    })
    }
```